# ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL socket in use

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html). This is the minimal example to reproduce the problem. After I start the producer process, consumer always complains that "Address already in use". But how can producer and consumer talk to each other if their ports are different? I'm using Python 3 and PyZMQ 16.0.3

Producer

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
zmq_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
zmq_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
for num in range(2000):
    work_message = { 'num' : num }
    zmq_socket.send_json(work_message)
```

Consumer

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
zmq_socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
zmq_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
for _ in range(2000):
    result = zmq_socket.recv_json()
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Ah, nevermind, it should have been `zmq_socket.connect` in Consumer, instead of `bind`. I'm very new to ZeroMQ, so I thought `bind` is the universal idiom.

Hope this helps any other new-comers.

Comment: Welcome. It is always helpful to at least search the StackOverflow portfolio of already asked / solved / discussed issues, isn't it? Never mind. +1 for a well documented MCVE case. All the best to Atlanta!

Comment: believe it or not, I had this exact mix up and couldnt figure it out from anywhere else, but when i searched for "python zmq PUSH/PULL socket in use" I got exactly the answer i needed! I was also using bind instead of connect. so this was very useful!